# Active Directory Schema Upgrade not enough to add new policy items

Tags: active-directory

I recently upgraded my AD Schema to 69 in the hopes that I would get the Policies / Admin Templated / Windows Components / Windows Update / "Always automatically restart at the scheduled time" for my Windows 8 / Windows Server 2012 machines.

I did this with adprep per [these instructions](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13422.manual-schema-upgrade-for-windows-server-2012windows-server-2012-r2.aspx).  But then, because "Policy definitions (ADMX files) retrieved from central store," I also had to copy a new ADMX file to my main SYSVOL...

Previously I don't believe I had to do this... is there a way to revert Active Directory to store all policy definitions IN Active Directory?!

It seems silly to need to upgrade the AD schema, and to have to add ADMX files to the central store.  Also, now I have some mixed version policies in the central store... a Windows Update.admx for schema version 69, while everything else is still version 47 I believe...

Posts like this one...

> In the field we commonly see two scenarios around the Central Store for Group Policy administrative templates. The first is that the Group Policy Central Store does not exist, meaning that the Policy Definitions folder with the administrative templates (.admx and .adml files) does not exist in SYSVOL. The second is that the Policy Definitions folder exists, but the .adm files are not removed from individual group polices thus negating a large benefit of the Central Store. In this post we want to walk you through how to fully implement the Central Store with a little help from our friend PowerShell.

["How to Implement the Central Store for Group Policy Admin Templates, Completely (Hint: Remove Those .ADM files!)"](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2011/12/12/how-to-implement-the-central-store-for-group-policy-admin-templates-completely-hint-remove-those-adm-files.aspx)

...make me feel like a central store is unnecessary.  Also, I've read warnings about blindly copying in ALL of the latest ADMX files to SYSVOL...

What is the proper way to fully upgrade my AD schema?!

Comment: `1.` Is a Central Store necessary? No, but it's strongly recommended. `2.` Updating the schema doesn't update/add the new ADMX templates AFAIK. Have a read here: http://deployhappiness.com/creating-the-group-policy-central-store-updated-for-windows-8-12012r2

Comment: I downloaded [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=43413), so it would appear all I need to do is copy in the ADMX files and the language files... correct?